# How to take object input in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, input

I have a part of form like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="gen.name" ng-repeat="gen in movie.genres">
```

`gen` in `movie.genre` is an object with 2 key value pairs

```
Object{
 id: 24,
 name : insidious
}
```

If I take the values on form submit I only get `gen.name` as value 
but I need the `id` of gen object as well.

So what can I do to get its id  as well?
Please note there are multiple input values as they are inside ng-repeat

Comment: `movie.genres` is an array of objects or just an object?

Comment: Create fiddle or plnkr.

Comment: You said *"movie.genre is an object"* in question. Update the question with proper info.  Where are you binding the `id` in your from?

Comment: @TJ I didnot understand your querry.
I am sending this id to the database as there are already genres created in the database with some ids .
So the  form input value name and id gets identified for future refrence.

Its like object already have genres can be modified with diffrent genre change.

Comment: @Invictus Your form should have a form control with the id as it's value. Otherwise why should the form submition send that information? So I'm asking where (on what element) you bound the `id` attribute of `gen`? BTW how exactly are you submitting this from?

Comment: Id is not bounded on any element.
Let me try to brief it again. Javascript contains an array [ obj, obj, obj]. obj here is diffrent movie generes with id and names. I am showing this to the viewer. And If viewer updates the input the, the updated value is stored in database with id. I dont know how to take id as there are multiple input values

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the id of the object which has the name of the selected genre.

Something like this should work (as long `movie.genres` is an array and `valueFromForm` is the value you get from your `ng-model`):

```
let index = movie.genres.findIndex(gen => gen.name === valueFromForm);
id = movie.genres[index].id;
```

This code uses ES6 so it needs recent browsers if you do not transcompile.
You can use this other version for older browsers:

```
var id = -1;
for (var i=0; i < movie.genres.length; i++) {
  if (movie.genres[i].name === valueFromForm) {
    id = movie.genres[i].id;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of exactly what you want. I hope this will help you fix your problem:

```js
angular.module('submitExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
        $scope.movie = {
         title: 'Movie Title',
            genres: [{
                name: 'Action'
            }, {
                name: 'Drama'
            }, {
                name: 'Comedy'
            }]
        };
        $scope.submit = function() {
            $log.info($scope.movie);
        };
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="submitExample">
    <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <input ng-model="gen.name" ng-repeat="gen in movie.genres"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```